# Почему программа не правильно считает элементы массива?

Tags: python, list

**Задача:**
*Дан одномерный массив (список), содержащий 20 элементов. Элементами массива являются случайные целые числа из
от -10 до 10. Напишите программу, которая вычисляет сумму первых 10 элементов и произведение последних 10 элементов, а также вычисляет количество положительных элементов.*

**Мой код:**

```
from random import randint
arrayLen20 = [randint(-10, 10) for i in range(20)]
halfLeftSum = 0
halfRightSum = 0
halfRightMult = 1
positiveNumbersCount = 0
for i, v in enumerate(arrayLen20):
    halfCount = (len(arrayLen20) / 2)
    if (i < halfCount):
    halfLeftSum += v
    if (i > halfCount):
    halfRightSum += v
    halfRightMult *= v
    if v > 0:
        positiveNumbersCount += 1
print(f"Весь массив: {arrayLen20}")
print(f"Сумма первой половины: {halfLeftSum}")
print(f"Сумма второй половины: {halfRightSum}")
print(f"Умножение второй половины: {halfRightMult}")
print(f"Количество положительных числа: {positiveNumbersCount}")
```

**Проблемы:**

1. Сумму второй половины считает не правильно
2. Умножение второй половины считает не правильно

Comment: поправь отступы

Comment: сумму первых 10 элементов и произведение последних 10 элементов, а не как у Вас написано в конце

Comment: У вас выпадает из расчётов элемент i == halfCount, видимо его то и не хватает во второй половине. Чтобы это равенство работало, когда вы его добавите, вычисляйте halfCount с помощью целочисленного деления // а не как сейчас

Comment: if (i >= halfCount): - для вычисления умножения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем Ваш вариант полностью. Без второй суммы, в задаче её нет

```
from random import randint
arrayLen20 = [randint(-10, 10) for i in range(20)]
halfLeftSum = 0
halfRightMult = 1
positiveNumbersCount = 0

arr_mul = []
arr_sum = []
for i, v in enumerate(arrayLen20):
    halfCount = (len(arrayLen20) // 2)
    if (i < halfCount):
        halfLeftSum += v
        arr_sum.append(v)
    else: #if (i >= halfCount):
        halfRightMult *= v
        arr_mul.append(v)
    if v > 0:
        positiveNumbersCount += 1

# Test mul array
res_mul = 1
for x in arr_mul:
    res_mul = res_mul * x

print(f"Весь массив: {arrayLen20}")
print(f"Сумма первой половины:     {arr_sum} {sum(arr_sum)} == {halfLeftSum}")
print(f"Умножение второй половины: {arr_mul} {res_mul} == {halfRightMult}")
print(f"Количество положительных числел: {positiveNumbersCount}")
```